# How to Install ubuntu on 2nd drive without affecting primary windows drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I have 2 drives an SSD which is my windows drive (C) and an HDD which I want to install ubuntu on (D) I want to install ubuntu on D in such a way that it does not affect the windows boot mgr on C and I need to use the bios to boot to D but automatically boots on C if I do not do anything

Comment: You can't boot to D until there is an OS on D. Burn an Ubuntu .iso onto a USB, boot from the live USB, and select to install on D. To be extra certain that the drives have no dependence on each other, you can remove the Windows drive from the device entirely when installing Ubuntu to the other drive.

Comment: Only afterwards, you can set your BIOS to boot to D (once it has Ubuntu installed), and you can set Ubuntu's GRUB bootloader to be able to load Windows if you want, so that way you don't have to mess with BIOS in between switching OSes

Comment: Future readers: Folks who are looking at dual-boot for trying Ubuntu, for occasional use, or for simultaneous use of both OS should also look at WSL and VM alternatives also. This question assumes that research and comparison has already occurred, and that dual-boot is preferable for this particular user.

Comment: You cannot install to D: that is a Windows NTFS partition. You will have to backup & delete D:. Make sure the HDD is gpt partitioning if Windows is UEFI. Since 2012 vendor installs of Windows are UEFI on gpt partitioned drives. Your Ubuntu install then needs to be UEFI, but to install boot loader on HDD, you must partition in advance & add ESP - efi system partition to HDD. Bug with work arounds: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 One work around: https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator

Answer (score 0):

You can't boot to D until there is an OS on D. Burn an Ubuntu .iso onto a USB, boot from the live USB, and select to install on D. To be extra certain that the drives have no dependence on each other, you can remove the Windows drive from the device entirely when installing Ubuntu to the other drive.